# Why does ReSharper's test runner ignore ExpectedException?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, resharper

when I run the following example with the debugger in Visual Studio 2010 (using TestDriven.NET), I get a pass, but when I run it with the ReSharper test runner, I get a fail. The test is written with Microsoft's test framework.

How can I set this up right? I basically just want to call a method with illegal input and I expect it to throw an exception.

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.Exception))]
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    throw new System.Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to use a less generic Exception (i.e, not System.Exception)

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))]
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
}
```

ReSharper seems to not handle ExpectedException with System.Exception that well, which in a way is good. Be specific about your exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Also, be sure to include the right version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Comment: Good point, I had exactly this issue with Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll. 10.1.0.0 didn't work. 10.0.0.0 did.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my problem. 10.1.0.0 does not work.